# I want to Align an item to the right in qml

Tags: qt, qml

```
Column {
                    id:column
                    spacing: 10
                    width: parent.width
      Repeater{
          model:5
                       Row {
                                  leftPadding:17
                                  topPadding:10
                                  spacing: 10
                                    Image {
                                             id:img
                                              height: 50
                                              width: 50
                                              source:"icon.png"
                                     }
                                    Text {
                                        text:"User_name"
                                        topPadding:12
                                   }
                                    Rectangle{
                                        height: 40
                                        width:40
                                        color: "#333333"
                                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                                    }
                                }
      }

  }
```

I have Used  Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight to show the rectangle to the right, But its not working. I don't understand why It is not working, I have also tried  Layout.fillWidth: true inside an Item but still not working

Comment: The `Layout` attached property only works if some code is reading it, which is `RowLayout`, `ColumnLayout` or `GridLayout`, all of which you are not using. Either switch to `ColumnLayout` or use `anchors.right: parent.right` (allthough I'm not sure it will work with a `Row`)

Comment: No it didn't work.

Comment: you mean anchors didn't work? Then try `RowLayout` with `Layout.fillWidth: true` on the `Text`. I realized you are putting stuff in a row, and RowLayout will only do vertical alignment, as well as ColumnLayout will only do horizontal layout (so perpendicular to the layout direction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amfasis pointed out, `Layout.alignment` doesn't do anything unless you're using one of QML's layout types. Here's a working example using `RowLayout`/`ColumnLayout`:

```
    ColumnLayout {
        id:column
        spacing: 10
        width: parent.width

        Repeater{
            model:5

            RowLayout {
                Layout.leftMargin: 17
                Layout.topMargin: 10
                spacing: 10

                Image {
                    id:img
                    source:"icon.png"
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 50
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                }
                Text {
                    text:"User_name"
                    topPadding:12
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                }
                Rectangle{
                    color: "#333333"
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 40
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 40
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                }
            }
        }
    }
```